# How to ping [some resource] on [some network] on an Android phone or emulator?

Tags: connection-issues

I have serious doubts that my emulator really can access a certain server. I want to confirm that by trying to ping the server. Is it possible, and how would I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ping utility from terminal emulator or adb shell.  Also: https://market.android.com/search?q=ping&so=1&c=apps

Comment: Solves the issue for a regular phone, but I also (and especially) want to know how to be able to do it on the emulator.

Comment: @Shathur: You can use the `ping` utility from terminal emulator or adb shell